# Missing result from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, task, intentfilter

I have two apps - App1 and App2. I have started App1 and I want to attach files from App2, which is already started in the background with its MainActivity (responsible for sharing the files).

When App2 is already in the background and I start MainActivity from App1, I do not get the files. However, if App2 wasn't started and is freshly started form App1 - it works fine. I also noticed that when App2 is in the background, the methods used for file sharing are called twice. I think that this is because I have two instances of MainActivity in two different tasks.

To avoid this, I am adding a filter to the Intent, that starts App2  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK - and App2's already running task is brought to front but I do not receive a result in App1. Does anybody have an idea why this is happening and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior - one task can not pass result to another